# SQL: Records showing blank during the execution of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am executing a query

```
Select * 
from Parking 
Where ParkingStartTime <> '08:00:00.0000000' 
  AND ParkingStartTime IS NULL
```

In return to the execution, the columns names are displayed but there records are not showing.

If I used OR Rather than AND it works. Any idea of why AND is not working?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ParkingStartTime is null, it can't have a value. This means that any value that meets the first part of the query cannot meet the second part of the query.

You either need just

```
ParkingStartTime is null
```

or

```
ParkingStartTime <> '08:00:00.000000'
```

Answer (score 5):

This can never return any results. The 2 conditions are contradictory.

If `ParkingStartTime IS NULL` then `ParkingStartTime <> '08:00:00.0000000'` will evaluate to `unknown`.

`True and Unknown` evaluates to `Unknown` under the truth tables for [3 valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ParkingStartTime cannot be both NULL (unknown) and also be equal to a particular value e.g. 08:00:00.0000000

The query does not return any values because your logic is incorrect.